# c# fill something on html page

Tags: c#-4.0

how can I fill  "MyUserName" on

```
<td width="18%" class="more"><div align="right">¿¿¿¿¿¿ </div></td>

<td width="82%">
    <font color="#FFFFFF" face="MS Sans Serif, Tahoma, sans-serif">
        <input type=text name="QTitle" size=51 maxlength=100 class=violet>
    </font>
</td>
```

i try in c# but it not work please help

```
private void webBrowser2_DocumentCompleted(object sender, 
                                           WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{

}

private void LoadProfileInformation()
{
    DataSet dsNew = new DataSet();

    //Some code to fetch information if you store it in a DB 
    //else you can put in static info if you may want. 
    //so you will nto need the dataset.



    QTitle.Text = "MyUserName";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the mark-up at the top of your question the resulting html or the source code for the form you are working with? If this is in-fact your asp.net form, try replacing the input tag with the following...

```
<asp:TextBox id="QTitle" runat="server" />
```

If the form is properly linked to the C# codebehind file you are using, QTitle.Text should now be accessible.

Comment: I use c# windows application please suggest

Comment: Replace input tag with asp: tag above, set QTitle.Text from your C# code. This should work. Note: Add the CssClass attribute to asp:TextBox if required.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in the class then access it with code behinds like `<%= myVar %>` in your front end.

if you want to modify the values of divs on the front end then you need to use asp tags like

```
<asp:label runat="server" name="Qtitle"> </asp:label>
```

Comment: I'd like to suggest you to edit your answer! his code has a text input, which isn't a label but a text box!! :D

Comment: you can use labels for text in asp

Answer (score 0):

First of all you really need to think about moving to newer versions of XHTML/HTML! (I suggest you that because of your markup code).

In the other hand, in order to get your "QTitle" text set from server, you'll need to set "runat" attribute to "server" in your input, but, if you're using standard (X)HTML elements, you won't have such property "Text".

I suggest you to use a server control like TextBox which has the whole "Text" property:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="QTitle" runat="server" CssClass="Violet" />
```

Some server code-behind:

```
QTitle.Text = "Hello world";
```

Another suggestion is you won't be setting any property after PreRender ASP.NET Page life-cycle event.